# how to apply price fetched from our own custom table in magento

Tags: magento

i want to apply prices fetched from my custom table (say my_own_prices). I have certain situation where i can’t use the prices of magento (like tiered price or special price), i need to fetch data from my table and apply it on shopping cart. Please reply if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `catalog_product_get_final_price` observer.

First declare observer in your module's (assuming you already have module) `etc/config.xml`:

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_get_final_price>
                <observers>
                    <something_unique_here>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductGetFinalPrice</method>
                    </something_unique_here>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_get_final_price>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Then in in your module's `Model\Observer.php` add the following method:

```
public function catalogProductGetFinalPrice($observer)
{
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();

    // Do your queries to your custom tables here and if necessary ..
    $product->setFinalPrice(..);
}
```

Comment: Hello Tim. First of all thanks for your reply. I have searched a lot about sales_quote_product_add_after but got no Idea how to add prices. Please guide me how could I apply prices. Ok I will give you example. I have a table in which "X" products price is 50. So what I want to do is, apply a check that if the product is X apply price 50 (fetched from my own table). Please help.

Comment: Please see my edit. Let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: Sir currently I am having one table which contains product and their price. Now I want something like when we open product page then we check if the product exist in my custom table, if yes then display that price(fetched from my custom table) and also when someone buy's that product this custom price should be applied. Please guide.